# Как можно получить неотправку UDP-датаграммы?

Tags: c++, c, сеть, udp

Я пишу UDP-клиент под Windows, и по заданию мне нужно доотправить те датаграммы, которые не дошли до сервера(о дошедших мне говорит сам сервер). Но когда я тестирую у себя в локальной сети, все пакеты доходят и проверить алгоритм доотправки нет возможности, как можно искусственно не отправить некоторые датаграммы, чтобы можно было проверить доотправку ?

Comment: @Mike Вопрос по ссылке к этому не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: На сервере-заглушке рандомно игнорируйте пакеты и все.

Comment: @VTT, я не управляю сервером, это руби скрипт

Comment: Тогда сначала сделайте сервер-заглушку, которым управляете

Comment: тогда в самом клиенте в функции непоследственно передающей пакет в сеть сделайте случайную не отправку. возвращайте статус что все ok, но сам пакет не доставляйте